# Got multiple values for argument 'Pattern' in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

*This is an 7 year old Django website and I'm trying to migrate it to the latest python version and got an error*

**Error**

urls.py

line 13, in

```
urlpatterns = [ path('CyberHealth.views',
TypeError: _path() got multiple values for argument 'Pattern'
```

This is my *urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [ path('CyberHealth.views',
    path('', views.index, name='index'),

    #==== Role ===

    path(r'^getorinsertroleAPI/$', views.getorinsertroleAPI, name='getorinsertroleAPI'),
    path(r'^updateordeleteroleAPI/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.updateordeleteroleAPI, name='updateordeleteroleAPI'),

    #==== Register ===

    path(r'^registerUser/$', views.registerUser, name='registerUser'),
    path(r'^registerFBUser/$', views.registerFBUser, name='registerFBUser'),
    path(r'^admin/registerCoach/$', views.reg
path(r'^user/detailViewofCoursePurchase/$', views.detailViewofCoursePurchase, name='detailViewofCoursePurchase'),

    
    path(r'^coach/listofPublishedCoursePayment/$', views.listofPublishedCoursePayment, name='listofPublishedCoursePayment'),
    path(r'^coach/totalEarningsInCourse/$', views.totalEarningsInCourse, name='totalEarningsInCourse'),
    path(r'^coach/courseTransactionHistory/$', views.courseTransactionHistory, name='courseTransactionHistory'),
    path(r'^coach/detailViewofCourseTransaction/$', views.detailViewofCourseTransaction, name='detailViewofCourseTransaction'),
    )]

urlpatterns += [ path('CyberHealth.views',
    path(r'^coach/totalEarningsbyCourse/$', views.totalEarningsbyCourse, name='totalEarningsbyCourse'),


    
    path(r'^admin/totalShareByCourse/$', views.totalShareByCourse, name='totalShareByCourse'),

    path(r'^admin/adminandcoachsharebyCourseid/$', views.adminandcoachsharebyCourseid, name='adminandcoachsharebyCourseid'),
    
    path(r'^admin/publishedCoursePaymentlist/$', views.publishedCoursePaymentlist, name='publishedCoursePaymentlist'),
    path(r'^admin/paymentHistoryforCourse/$', views.paymentHistoryforCourse, name='paymentHistoryforCourse'
))]
```

There are more than 500 urls , so I have sorted listed these and these are the exact format.

Comment: The first list element `path('CyberHealth.views',` has no closing bracket and is missing some parameters. Look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urls/#path

Comment: Hi @mailivres..Sorry can you view my updated post that I have edited now

Answer (score 0):

The first list entry causes the problem: `path('CyberHealth.views',`
it should look look like this `path('HERE_YOUR_PATH/', VIEW_NAME, name='PATH_NAME')`
Orient yourself to the other path objects.
And when you add the closing bracket (and a comma) you have to delete a closing bracket at the end of the list to remove syntax errors.

Comment: Hii @mailivres can you give me a sample as I am new I can't quite  understand you

Comment: At second glance I see a `urlpatterns += [ path('CyberHealth.views',` code line in the middle of the code snippet which make no sense.
Your urlpatterns list seems to be corrupted. You have to clean up here.
I would try to remove `path('CyberHealth.views',` at the beginning and `urlpatterns += [ path('CyberHealth.views',` in the middle of your snippet. Then clean up syntax errors (remove and add wrong brackets)

Comment: As you said I have removed those and came to this error. conf.py", line 67, in _path
    urlconf_module, app_name, namespace = view
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Comment: Try this: https://pastebin.pl/view/raw/7f8c9013

Comment: Still the same error continues @mailvres   conf.py", line 67, in _path
    urlconf_module, app_name, namespace = view   ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Comment: does the traceback reference to the above edited urls.py? If not, I would say this is another error.